# Puzzling xml select syntax in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

In the below sql code, what does T(C) mean? What is T and what is C?

```
declare @employeeData xml --this would be your XML input parameter
set @employeeData = '<employeeData>
<employee LastName="Smith" FirstName="Randolph" EmployeeID="1234567"/>
</employeeData>'

declare @xmlTable table (LastName nvarchar(255), FirstName nvarchar(255), EmployeeID int)

insert into @xmlTable (LastName, FirstName, EmployeeID)
select 
C.value('@LastName','nvarchar(255)') as LastName,
C.value('@FirstName','nvarchar(255)') as FirstName,
C.value('@EmployeeID','int') as EmployeeID
from
@employeeData.nodes('/employeeData/employee') T(C)

select * from @xmlTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

T - Table
C - Column

Comment: Thank you. Apparently my google skills still suck. I searched long and hard but didnt know what to search for in msdn

Comment: Thanks. And wish you the same.

Comment: Feel free to up-vote my question when you hit 15 points in reputation which will happen as soon as I accept your answer. The stackoverflow system only allows you to accept after 15 minutes :P